# Differential Equation for Algorithm Time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, algorithms, asymptotics, analysis-of-algorithms

I'm working on algorithm analysis and time complexity. I've got a homework assignment to calculate a function f(n) at time t and I want to figure out how to write it as a differential equation. Haven't taken differential equations so I'm having a tough time getting it together.

So largest size $n$ of a problem that can be solved in time $t$.

If an algorithm takes $f(n)$ microseconds to solve, whats the largest size it can solve in time $t$.
$f(n) = \sqrt{n}$.

At $t=1$, $n=10^{12}$

At $t=60$, $n=36*10^{14}$

...etc

I hope I'm being concise in my question, I'm a bit frazzled at this point. Its not a matter of finding the answers, I can do that. But I want to figure out how to construct an equation to represent this.

Comment: I don't think a "differential equation" is what you want (are you taking derivatives of anything?).  Tell me if I am summarizing your question correctly: Find the largest $n$ satisfying the inequality $\sqrt{n} \leq 10^6 t$.  In this case, since the function $\sqrt{n}$ is strictly increasing, this is equivalent to just solving $\sqrt{n} = 10^6 t$.

Comment: You summarized correctly, and the inequality does satisfy. I believe you may be right, but I was thinking its possible to represent this as diff equation since I'm looking at f(n)=n, n^2,n^3,2^n.